# TensorFlow & Keras installation

Tags: python

Can anyone explain to me how I should install Tensorflow and Keras on Ubuntu? Preferably in combination with python 3.6? The pip installation suggested at the TensorFlow website offers no solution (python cannot find the package when I try to import TensorFlow). Apart from the Tensorflow website, I can find only very limited supplementary documentation.

Comment: If package cannot be found, maybe wrong python version is used or a firewall is blocking something (e.g. if you are in a company network)

Answer (score 0):

To install keras using command line : 
  pip3 install keras

To install tensorflow using command line :
python3 -m pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-1.12.0-py3-none-any.whl

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use Miniconda and always create an own virtual environment for my projects, here called myenv (should be a usefull name). Everything done via command line. If you are not familar with command line, please consider to use Anaconda instead.

1) Download Miniconda
https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html

2) Install Miniconda (from you download folder)

```
bash Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh
```

3) Update Conda

```
conda update conda
```

4) Create virtual environment (myenv) for actual project with certain Python version

```
conda create -n myenv python=3.6
```

5) Install necessary packages into virtual environment

If you will use CPU

```
conda install -n myenv tensorflow keras
```

If you will use GPU

```
conda install -n myenv tensorflow-gpu keras
```

maybe you will need further packages, depends on your situation (hdf5, h5py, graphiz, pydot, cudnn)

6) Activate virtual environment (for running your tensorflow environment)

```
conda activate myenv
```

7) Deactivate virtual environment (if you would like to go back to base)

```
conda deactivate
```

or

```
conda activate base
```